# How to link two classes in Java without functions

Tags: java

In Eclipse I've created a (Project > Package > Classes(HelloWorld.java, HelloUniverse.java )

How do I connect the second class to the main function,

```
package com.shindeaditya.first;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String args [])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        new HelloUniverse();
    }

}
```

```
package com.shindeaditya.first;

public class HelloUniverse {
    public void helloUniverse() {
        System.out.println("Hello everyone I'm new to JAVA");
    }

}
```

So that I get the output as

```
Hello World
Hello everyone I'm new to JAVA
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "connect" here. Are the classes in the same package? Do you get any compile error? If so, please include it in the question

Comment: What do you mean by "without functions"?

Comment: just call that method. "without functions", they're actually methods, so technically, no functions were involved (though that is just semantics). Yes, you need to actually call the method for it to execute.

Comment: There is no _linker_ in Java. Do you mean how you deliver both class files in a way that they "know" each other during runtime?

Comment: Change second line of main() to:  (new HelloUniverse()).helloUniverse();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this:

1: Change the function so it becomes the constructor, Remove the void and make the first letter a capital letter like the class name.
Source: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_constructors.asp

```java
package com.shindeaditya.first;

public class HelloUniverse {
    public HelloUniverse() {
        System.out.println("Hello everyone I'm new to JAVA");
    }
}
```

2: Call the function on the object, by saving it (for example) to an object and calling the function method.
Source: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_class_methods.asp

```java
package com.shindeaditya.first;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String args [])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        
        // with a seperate variable
        HelloUniverse universe = new HelloUniverse();
        universe.helloUniverse();
        
        // in one line
        (new HelloUniverse()).helloUniverse();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Change the function so it behaves like the constructor", actually, what you did there was putting that statement in a constructor. A constructor acting like a constructor? 
You don't need to have a variable, new HelloUniverse().helloUniverse(); works just fine